# Display simple HTML help file in Qt on Android

Tags: android, html, c++, qt, qwebview

Qt doesn't support HTML view (`QWebView`) for Android yet. I have some help files created in HTML. The format is simple, only using basic CSS styles, images and no javascript at all. I need to display these on Android within the Qt C++ application.

Is there alternative to `QWebView` that works with simple HTML and CSS? Or is there other rich text format I could convert the HTML to and then display in Qt application?

Opening help in another program is not an option.

Comment: Can you help me understand why opening help in another program is not an option? This is the typical behavior of desktop applications.

Comment: @JonathanMee Because android applications are not desktop applications. When you go to other application, android may terminate the application you left. The help is not huge repository of text and should be quickly accessible. Or would you be comfortable starting Firefox on your phone every time you need help about configuration item?

Comment: Android will *not* close the application when starting the default browser as this is the spawning process, so I still think that's your best option. But if you can convert to simple HTML, getting rid of the CSS, even `QLabel`s can display that.

Comment: Take a look at QML's WebView, which uses the platform's native web renderer. Android is fully supported: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html

Comment: @MrEricSir I found about that. I tried to use it but it does not compile - either the library is broken (wouldn't surprise me) or I need to use one of those `QT += ...` in project file. If so, I don't know which one.

Comment: As far as I know all you need are `qml` and `quick`. Works fine for me on my Android tablet.